# Very slow filtering and ordering big table by set in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, optimization, filtering

I have a SQL Server database (versions 2012, 2014) and have a table with many attributes (ca 50). The table has 50,000 rows.

I want to filter and order this table, for example:

```
select id, ... 
from mytable 
where attr = 3 
order by id
```

This is not slow, it is working well.

But I have a need to filter out the rows which the user cannot see. There exists a view, which generates a table with ids which the user can see.

Then comes the simple join:

```
select id, ... 
from mytable
inner join can_see_view on mytable.id = can_see_view.id
where attr = 3 
order by id
```

This is somewhat very slow. The execution plan is:

[image]

I tried to save the can_see ids into a temporary table (@ids) - this is visible on the execution plan.

Whatever I do (inner join, left outer join, intersect, in, exists) it is slow as hell.

How to optimize this? Maybe add an index? Or some other trick??

Edit: 
sort tooltip:

[image]

### Edit - sample data

```
create table dbo.bigtable (
    id int not null identity (1,1),
    attr1 varchar(4000) null,
    attr2 varchar(4000) null,
    attr3 varchar(4000) null,
    attr4 varchar(4000) null,
    attr5 varchar(4000) null,
    attr6 varchar(4000) null,
    attr7 varchar(4000) null,
    attr8 varchar(4000) null,
    attr9 varchar(4000) null,
    attr10 varchar(4000) null,
    attr11 varchar(4000) null,
    attr12 varchar(4000) null,
    attr13 varchar(4000) null,
    attr14 varchar(4000) null,
    attr15 varchar(4000) null,
    attr16 varchar(4000) null,
    attr17 varchar(4000) null,
    attr18 varchar(4000) null,
    attr19 varchar(4000) null,
    attr20 varchar(4000) null,
    attr21 varchar(4000) null,
    attr22 varchar(4000) null,
    attr23 varchar(4000) null,
    attr24 varchar(4000) null,
    attr25 varchar(4000) null,
    attr26 varchar(4000) null,
    attr27 varchar(4000) null,
    attr28 varchar(4000) null,
    attr29 varchar(4000) null,
    attr30 varchar(4000) null,
    attr31 varchar(4000) null,
    attr32 varchar(4000) null,
    attr33 varchar(4000) null,
    attr34 varchar(4000) null,
    attr35 varchar(4000) null,
    attr36 varchar(4000) null,
    attr37 varchar(4000) null,
    attr38 varchar(4000) null,
    attr39 varchar(4000) null,
    attr40 varchar(4000) null,
    attr41 varchar(4000) null,
    attr42 varchar(4000) null,
    attr43 varchar(4000) null,
    attr44 varchar(4000) null,
    attr45 varchar(4000) null,
    attr46 varchar(4000) null,
    attr47 varchar(4000) null,
    attr48 varchar(4000) null,
    attr49 varchar(4000) null,
    attr50 varchar(4000) null
)

GO

create function canseefunc ()
returns @result table (id int null)
as
begin
insert into @result(id)
    select id from bigtable -- no logic, can see everything
    return
end

create view dbo.cansee
as
    select id from canseefunc()
    --select id from bigtable

GO

declare @i int
set @i = 0

while (@i < 50000)
begin
    insert into dbo.bigtable (attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5, attr6, attr7, attr8, attr9, attr10,
    attr11, attr12, attr13, attr14, attr15, attr16, attr17, attr18, attr19, attr20,
    attr21, attr22, attr23, attr24, attr25, attr26, attr27, attr28, attr29, attr30,
    attr31, attr32, attr33, attr34, attr35, attr36, attr37, attr38, attr39, attr40,
    attr41, attr42, attr43, attr44, attr45, attr46, attr47, attr48, attr49, attr50)
    values (
    CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),
    CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),
    CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),
    CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),
    CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),
    CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),
    CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),
    CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),
    CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),
    CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()))

    set @i = @i + 1
end

GO

select b.id 
from bigtable as b
inner join cansee as c on b.id = c.id
where attr41 <> 'aa'
order by b.id, b.attr10
```

As you can see, I am using a function, which computes the ids which the user can see. If I remove the function and simple use the view directly, without calling the function, it is not slow! Why is this?

Comment: Can you include the table definitions and view definition?  Perhaps some sample rows for each and the output you would expect from the sample?

Comment: 1. You see that exclamation mark over the sort operator? hover over it and find out what it is. 2. Does the plan suggest any indexes (in green). Given that the sort operator contributes 63% of the cost, most of the issue is in your order by. Is it any quicker without your order by?

Comment: I added the sort tooltip. Even if I omit the order by, the sort step remains... No indexes suggested.

Comment: Do you have 'DISTINCT' or `INSERT INTO`/`SELECT INTO` somewhere in your complete query?

Comment: No, absolutely not. The query is a simple inner join without distinct.

Comment: @dimitrij you don't insert your data enywhere, don't sort it, don't have distinct, this is your full code and you are still having `SORT` operator _in the end_ of _actual_ execution plan?

Comment: added sample code, you can see my code now...

Comment: `order by b.id, b.attr10` - ?

Comment: yeah, but it could be anything, any attribute. The user can choose ordering freely. attr10 is just for example.

Comment: I'll have to say that wrapping a table variable function in a view is probably horrible. Also, you are ordering by a varchar(4000) field as well as performing an inequality on a varchar(4000) field. How can you expect that to be fast?

Comment: Wrapping a function in a view is horrible, that's right. But the business logic is very complex and we need variables etc. That's why it is a function and not simple a view.

Comment: The bigger issue is probably sorting by that varchar(4000) field. SQL Server doesn't know the exact lenght of all of the fields, so when it executes the query, it has to estimate how much memory to allocate for the sorting operation. When it misjudges, it has to spill out to tempdb, which is what your error message is saying.

Answer (score 1):

Your order by is the perf killer here.
Are you using an indexed column from *mytable*
If id is your PK for *mytable* then it shouldn't be an issue.

Otherwise you can add an index. 
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_can_see_view_id ON can_see_view (id);

In your case, you can also avoid the join by using a in clause like this:

```
SELECT
    t.id
FROM
    mytable t
WHERE
    t.attr = 3
    AND t.id IN (SELECT * FROM can_see_view)
ORDER BY
    t.id;
```

Plus the join condition column should have the exact same datatype including size/precision to get the best performance.